How to detect OS theme change by User in MAC OS?
I have a webapplication, where the front end is in Angular, Backend is in C#. We wrapped it inside QT as a desktop application. I'm implementing theming (Light, Dark and Auto) for the app. When Auto is set, I need to change the app theme to the OS theme. If the app theme is set to Auto and the OS theme is changed from Light to Dark, I need to render the app in Dark mode. To do this, I need to listen to the OS theme changes. I could do it for Windows using SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged event
from Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.
However I'm not able to detect OS theme changes in MAC OS. I tried p/Invoke to access MAC API's but it didn't work.
public class ThemeChangeDetector
{

    private const string CoreFoundationLibrary = "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation";

    [DllImport(CoreFoundationLibrary)]
    private static extern IntPtr CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter();

    [DllImport(CoreFoundationLibrary)]
    private static extern void CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(IntPtr center, IntPtr observer, CFNotificationCallback callback, IntPtr name, IntPtr obj, uint suspensionBehavior);

    private delegate void CFNotificationCallback(IntPtr center, IntPtr observer, IntPtr name, IntPtr obj, IntPtr userInfo);

    private static CFNotificationCallback callback = new CFNotificationCallback(NotificationCallback);

    private static void NotificationCallback(IntPtr center, IntPtr observer, IntPtr name, IntPtr obj, IntPtr userInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Theme changed!");
        // Handle theme change
    }

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        IntPtr center = CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter();

        CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(center, IntPtr.Zero, callback, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
    }
}

Any Idea why?

Sounds like the theme change should be detected at the Qt-level and passed to the   backend somehow.  I think that has more chance of working.

QT version we are using is 5.14, but OS theme detection is possible with QT version 6.5. So I'm consideing p/Invoke in C# (in backend)

See How to subscribe to system changes on MacOS?
